# Read values from SPI (GPIO bus) and send values over ethernet

Tags: c, sockets, raspberry-pi, ethernet

I'm new to C and for a homework exam I must implement a simple server socket program which sends some data in a loop and if the client is connected to the server socket(have done it with Arduino but need the same functionallity on raspberrypi or other sbc).

For example (arduino style):

```
EthernetServer server = EthernetServer(23);
// start listening for clients
server.begin();
int i = 0;
while(true){
  i++;

  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
     while (client.connected()) {
     if (client.available()) {
      client.print(i);
     }
    }
   }
   client.stop;
}
```

I have a SBC (single board computer) with GPIO buss. My program must:

- read values from SPI bus (infinite loop)
- if the client is connected to the server scoket It must send some values to the client.

I know how to implement this kind of app in Java but in C, I don't have enaugh knowledge. 
I'am looking for some kind of library or example on how to implement it.

regards

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 1):

You can refer below mentioned link to establish a client/server connection using sockets with RPi with C implementation. Hope it helps you.

http://cs.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Tutorial:_Client/Server_on_the_Raspberry_Pi